# Loading a precompiled jasper file throws an exception: Class not found when loading object from file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Using *JasperReports 6.11.0* in Eclipse, I precompiled a *.jrxml* file into a *.jasper* file. My problem is when I use the *jasper* file to load as a report, it throws an exception `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading object from file`. This is the code I am using:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader
                .loadObjectFromFile("src/main/resources/Report.jasper");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Note that I tried using a template and still throws the same exception. Also, when I compile the jrxml in the Java code, it works perfectly.

```
InputStream input = new ClassPathResource("jasper.jrxml").getInputStream();
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Comment: Your example is working great without any issues. You should post small *jrxml* (to reproduce the issue) and show the project structure. What version of jdk and JasperReports library are you using? Did you try the same using basic console application (just main method)? Are you using maven or gradle?

Comment: Hi @AlexK, I have tried it in just a simple maven project and it still has the issue. I am using Java 8 and jasperreports 6.11.0.

Comment: Hi @AlexK, I made it work by using 6.15. Thank you. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The simple *jxml* is working fine with *jr 6.11.0*. Are you able to reproduce the issue using simple *jrxml* (for example having one staticText at title)?

Comment: Yes. It still has the same issue after trying that.

Answer (score 0):

Swap your search path for this:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new 
FileInputStream(Faces.getRealPath(inside webapp "/reports/yourfile.jrxml"));
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).